# How to place a transparent image on top of another image?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've tried placing a png image with a java.lang.String source on top of another image. I expected the top image to be transparent such that the bottom image would also appear, but it didn't work. Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Show your code and your results

Answer (score 0):

use z-index to position the top image over the bottom image and opacity to set the transparency of the top image.

Without some code to look at, (or a fiddle), it is harder to be more exact.